# Can ruby's ObjectSpace get any string？

Tags: ruby

I know that the ObjectSpance get string like these:

```
strings = ObjectSpace.each_object(String);
```

but it is not all string in ruby; if I want to get a local_variables like these:

```
module My

  def self.test
    a = "I'm a string"
  end

end
```

to get "`I'm a string"`, ObjectSpace can do it?

Comment: There's no reason to think that `"I'm a string"` exists as an instance of `String` when the `My.test` method is not executing, is there? If you `ObjectSpace.each_object(String)` from inside `My.test` (or somewhere with `My.test` in the call stack) then you'd find it, but probably not otherwise unless you want to try parsing all the source (and even then you'd run into problems due to how dynamic Ruby is).

Comment: I want  to encode my ruby code, then get  it back in a method, but some people say that he can get source code from ObjectSpace, I wonder if it is true. but  I don't know how to do it

Comment: Source code is not an object, and does not exist in `ObjectSpace`. But you can read it simply by looking at the `.rb` file. What do you mean, "encode my ruby code"?

Comment: for example, we can use base64 to encode string, but we will get it back in somewhere, like 
Base64.encode64("original sring") => "b3JpZ2luYWwgc3Jpbmc="
I write "b3JpZ2luYWwgc3Jpbmc=" in encode.rb
then I need get it back in a function, like

`module My

  def self.test
 file = File.open("encode.rb")
 content = file.read
 back = Base64.decode64(content)
  end

end`

so my question is that "back" is in ObjectSpace?

Answer (score 0):

Strings, within the scope in which they are defined, do "not know" which local variables, if any, hold their value. That is, that information cannot be obtained from the string alone. For example, for `a=['cat', 'dog']`, `'cat'` and `'dog'` are held by no local variable, in `a = b = 'cat'`, `'cat'` is held by two local variables. Moreover, two identical (unfrozen) strings are different objects. So even if we could somehow use `ObjectSpace.each_obect(String)` to somehow bore into methods for all class instances (which we can't) we would be unable to retrieve the desired information.

Nor can we identify local variables within methods and then determine their values. That is because the only time they may exist is after the method is called and before it returns, and that information is not available outside the method. Moreover, it may change during the execution of the method.

At any point in time the local variables and their values can be obtained (but only from within the method) as follows.

```
def at
  b = 3
  c = 4
  local_variables.map { |v| [v, binding.local_variable_get(v)] }.to_h
end

at
  #=> {:b=>3, :c=>4}
```

This is no help in answering the OP's question, however.

The situation is somewhat different is we were asked to identify, at a given point in time, all *instance* variables and their values for each existing instance of each existing class (so we could then confine our attention to instances variables holding strings).

Suppose, for example, we define the following class.

```
class Z
  def initialize(str1, str2)
    @z1, @z2 = str1, str2
  end
end
```

and create two instances of this class.

```
mimi_fufu = Z.new 'mimi', 'fufu'
  #=> #<Z:0x00000001269160 @z1="mimi", @z2="fufu">
fido_biff = Z.new 'fido', 'biff'
  #=> #<Z:0x000000012772b0 @z1="fido", @z2="biff">
```

Now, `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class)` returns an array of all classes presently defined, one being `Z`, and `ObjectSpace.each_object(Z)` returns an array of all instances of `Z`. We therefore could perform the following calculation to obtain the desired information for `Z` (and hence, for every other existing class).

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Z).map do |inst|
  { instance: inst,
    inst_vars: inst.instance_variables.each_with_object({}) { |iv,h|
      h[iv] = inst.instance_variable_get(iv) } }
end
  #=> [{:instance=>#<Z:0x00000001269160 @z1="mimi", @z2="fufu">,
  #     :inst_vars=>{:@z1=>"mimi", :@z2=>"fufu"}},
  #    {:instance=>#<Z:0x000000012772b0 @z1="fido", @z2="biff">,
  #     :inst_vars=>{:@z1=>"fido", :@z2=>"biff"}}]
```

See [#instance_variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables) and [#instance_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get).